# tail -100 catalina.out | mail to somewhere

Tags: linux, scripting

trying to spit out last 100 lines of catalina.out and email them to myself.  Can someone suggest a quick oneliner on how to do this?

I can only come up with something like:

```
tail -100 catalina.out | /bin/mail -s blah myemailaddress
```

Comment: What's wrong with your version?

Comment: so.... you have a solution. It works. It fits on one line. What's the question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend using

`tail -100 catalina.out | /bin/mail -s blah myemailaddress`

I think you should find the results handy.

Comment: add the 2>&1 bit to get the errors as well :)

Answer (score 5):

What you've got will work just fine.

Comment: do you think its appropriate to add this method to commands that take a long time, and you want to be notified when they complete?

Comment: @Clustermagnet I do that all the time.  I even do that to commands that should never complete, so I'm notified if they do.  If it makes a lot of noise then I might not pipe the output to the email though.  Something like `runforever >/dev/null | mail me@example.com -s "runforever didn't"`

Comment: You could do, alternatively you could wrap the command in a script, redirect the command's output to a file, wait for it to finish, test it's return status and send an email based on that.